# Not able to center email input element

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment, bootstrap-4

I am working on product landing page as a part of freecodecamp bootcamp. I am using the bootstrap library.

I am not able to center the email input in the form. I  tried using 12 columns which fixes the issue but it is very large. I want it to occupy space of 6 columns but also align it in the center.

[Codepen is here.](https://codepen.io/thesohelshaikh/pen/mKqYMx)

```css
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    body {
    }

    main {
      max-width: 1000px;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    #hero {
      background-color: #FFF;
    }
    #video {
      margin-top: 50px;
    }
    h1{
      margin: 20px;
    }
    section{
      margin: 50px;
    }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>

<body>
  <header id="header">
    <nav id="nav-bar" class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg fixed-top bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://png.icons8.com/nolan/50/000000/bank-building.png" id="header-img" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
        OmegaStocks
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#hero">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#features">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main class="container">
    <section id="hero" class="jumbotron text-center">
      <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Subscribe to our weekly newsletter</h1>
        <div class="container">
          <form class="" action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit" id="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input id="email" type="email" name="email" value="" class="form-control col-sm-6" placeholder="Enter your email address" required/>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
          </form>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="features">
      <h1>features</h1>
      <div class="container marketing">
        <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://png.icons8.com/nolan/96/000000/coins.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
            <h2>Best in class</h2>
            <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
          </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://png.icons8.com/nolan/96/000000/money-box.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
            <h2>Effective</h2>
            <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
          </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://png.icons8.com/nolan/96/000000/bitcoin.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
            <h2>Accurate</h2>
            <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
          </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
      <div class="container">
        <iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pXRviuL6vMY" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </iframe>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="pricing">
      <h1>pricing</h1>
      <div class="container">
      <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Free</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$0 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>10 users included</li>
              <li>2 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Pro</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$15 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>20 users included</li>
              <li>10 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Priority email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Enterprise</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$29 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>30 users included</li>
              <li>15 GB of storage</li>
              <li>Phone and email support</li>
              <li>Help center access</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Contact us</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer class="container py-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md">
          <img src="https://png.icons8.com/nolan/50/000000/bank-building.png" alt="">
          <small class="d-block mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2018</small>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md">
          <h5>Features</h5>
          <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
            <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Cool stuff</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Random feature</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Team feature</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Stuff for developers</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Another one</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Last time</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md">
          <h5>Resources</h5>
          <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
            <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Resource</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Resource name</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Another resource</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Final resource</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md">
          <h5>Resources</h5>
          <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
            <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Business</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Education</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Government</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Gaming</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md">
          <h5>About</h5>
          <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
            <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Team</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Locations</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Privacy</a></li>
            <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Terms</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved your problem  please check following code 'section id="hero"'

```
<section id="hero" class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Subscribe to our weekly newsletter</h1>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
        <form class="" action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit" id="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="email" type="email" name="email" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email address" required/>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

just set your #email element to use margin auto.

```
#email {
 margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: This does solve the problem but isn't clean. As I am using bootstarp, it is better to fix it with bootstrap classes rather than additional code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use offset-sm-3 to center the input element.

```
<input id="email" type="email" name="email" value="" class="form-control col-sm-6 offset-sm-3" placeholder="Enter your email address" required/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a row with three columns if you want to center the form.  Two columns with 3 as the values in each side of a 6 value column.

Sometimes the columns work against you, that is just an easy fix that worked for me.